# Powershell DSC - Unzip file to remote destination

Tags: powershell, automation, hyper-v, powershell-dsc

My goal is to create a **Powershell DSC** configuration to unzip a file - from my local computer - to a remote directory on a Hyper-V **Win10 VM** (I've already shared that destination folder). But, right now, I still have some problem to insert the VM credentials inside the .ps1. This is my code:

```
Configuration CopyTest {

Node 'localhost'
{
        User Admin
    {
        UserName = "Admin"
        Password = "Password"
        Ensure = "Present"
    }

    Archive ArchiveExample {
        Ensure = 'Present'
        Path = 'C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test.zip'
        Destination = '\\DESKTOP-HEFLNJ6\destination'
    }
}

}
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to insert the **Windows credentials** (of the remote machine) inside the Powershell script?

Thanks for your time...hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use credential in you DSC configuration.
Below documentations will help you to achieve it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/runasuser

below is a small example which uses credential in a DSC configuration.

```
configuration FileCopy
{
Param(
    [PSCredential]$Credential
)
    node localhost
    {
        File CopyFile{
            Ensure = 'Present'
            DestinationPath = '\\server\share'
            SourcePath = 'c:\sourcepath'
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $Credential
        }
    }
}
```